# Extract Key/Value Pair from JSON string and keep special characters in Value

Tags: json, regex, vb.net

I have an Html page that has various JSON arrays. I am using the HTML Agility Pack to grab the innerText from the page which isolates some left over texts and the JSON arrays in the page (there are many complex ojbects in the page). I then pass the text to the RegEx as shown below and it parses the Key/Value pairs; however it stops at the apostrophe; however I need that and would like to keep the special characters to support other functions.

I sourced the RegEx from the internet and I am sure it needs a tweak to allow special characters.  I have tried all kinds of methods; but not being an expert in RegEx, I am unable to come up with a solution.  Does anyone have some suggestions on how to fix the RegeEx?

```
Dim some_json As String = """{""request"":""Over the last 25 years, I've worked with most of the worldâ€™s leading selling strategy systems and built sales training used by companies on six continents. Two years ago, I teamed up with other sales strategy experts to merge our combined experience, wisdom and knowledge into an artificial intelligence system. We worked with expert neuroscientists, behavioral economists, psychologists, and AI programmers to develop JOY, the worldâ€™s first emotionally intelligent and sales-savvy artificial intelligence system for sales.  Now I focus on helping companies implement JOY to instantly increase sales and dominate markets.  \n "",""status"":200}"""

        some_json = some_json.Replace("\n", " ")

        Dim r As Regex = New Regex("""(?<Key>[\w]*)"":""?(?<Value>([\s\w\d\.\\\-/:_\+]+(,[,\s\w\d\.\\\-/:_\+]*)?)*)""?")
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = r.Matches(some_json)

        'regex returns summary: Over the last 25 years, I
        'how do I return the entire value with the apostrophe's, special characters?

        For Each k As Match In mc
            Try
                If (k.Groups("Value").Value.Length > 0 And k.Groups("Key").Value = "request") Then
                    m = m & k.Groups("Key").Value & ":" & k.Groups("Value").Value.ToString & "<br/><br/>"
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim se As String = ex.Message
            End Try
        Next
        Response.Write(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by throwing out the RegEx and used a a recursive function to pull anything from any depth of json. It outputs name/value pairs.  If there is a deep object it stacks up the key names (ex. depth4.depth3.depth2) and then follows with the value.  So a simple string compare on the key (combo) and you can pull out the value.

```
Private Shared Function ParseJson(ByVal token As JToken, ByVal nodes As Dictionary(Of String, String), ByVal Optional parentLocation As String = "") As Boolean
    If token.HasValues Then

        For Each child As JToken In token.Children()

            If token.Type = JTokenType.[Property] Then

                If parentLocation = "" Then
                    parentLocation = (CType(token, JProperty)).Name
                Else
                    parentLocation += "." & (CType(token, JProperty)).Name
                End If
            End If

            ParseJson(child, nodes, parentLocation)
        Next

        Return True
    Else

        If nodes.ContainsKey(parentLocation) Then
            nodes(parentLocation) += "|" & token.ToString()
        Else
            nodes.Add(parentLocation, token.ToString())
        End If

        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Private Sub Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim ServerPath As String = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
    Dim left_overs As String = String.Empty

    'download web page
    Dim html = New HtmlDocument()
    html.LoadHtml(New WebClient().DownloadString(ServerPath & "files/somefile.htm"))

    Dim txt As String = html.DocumentNode.InnerText, m As String = String.Empty

    Try
        Dim ndes As Array = html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cde").ToArray
        For Each item As HtmlNode In ndes

            Dim s As String = item.InnerText.Trim
            'Response.Write(s)
            Try

                Dim nodes As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)()
                Dim rootObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(s)
                ParseJson(rootObject, nodes)

                For Each key As String In nodes.Keys
                    If key = "included.summary" Then

                        left_overs = AlphaNumericOnly(nodes(key))
                        m = m & key & " = " & left_overs & "<br/><br/>"
                        Response.Write(m)
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception
                Dim err As String = ex.Message
            End Try

        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

End Sub
```

And a little bit of a cleanup function.

```
Public Shared Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strResult As String = String.Empty

    For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
            Case 32 To 91, 93 To 126 'include 32 if you want to include space
                strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        End Select
    Next
    AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```